# AngularJS, Nodejs and Nginx application returns 404 when trying to hit endpoint

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx

So, I have tried to put a Nginx reverse proxy between my AngularJS client and the NodeJS server. All my static files are served as expected but some routes which are accessed using $http.get from an Angular service return 404. (such as app.get('/sessionInit') or app.get('/login')).

I will append to this some relevant parts of my code hoping that hey might help you in any way.

**This is my API endpoint:**

```
app.get('sessionInit', function(req, res){
    if(sess){
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            code : 610,
            scope : "session",
            message : "Session on the way !",
            session : sess
        }));
    }else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            code : 613,
            scope : "session",
            message : "Session does not exists or has expired please log in again.",
            session : null
        }));
    }
});
```

**This is my angular request:**

```
    this.getSession = function getSession(){
                var promise = $http({
                    url: '/sessionInit',
                    method: "GET"
                }).then(function (result) {
                    if(result.data.code == 610){
                        //update browser cookies
                        $cookies.putObject("userSession", result.data.session);
                        setUserInfo();
                        if(typeof($cookies.get("userSession")) != null) return $cookies.get("userSession");
                        else return null;
                    }else{
                        console.log(result.data.code, result.data.message, result.data.session);
                        return null;
                    }
                });

                return promise;
            };
```

**This is my nginx config file:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/law-bid-nodejs;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name *mypublicip*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$http_origin';
        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Accept,Content-Type, Origin';
        proxy_redirect off;         
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

When trying to request the 'sessionInit' with angular from my NodeJS server where I have my route it is returning a *publicip*/sessionInit 404 not found error.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `/` before `sessionInit`

```
app.get('/sessionInit', function(req, res){
    if(sess){
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            code : 610,
            scope : "session",
            message : "Session on the way !",
            session : sess
        }));
    }else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            code : 613,
            scope : "session",
            message : "Session does not exists or has expired please log in again.",
            session : null
        }));
    }
});
```

In your Nginx config `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` will also cause an issue. `/sessionInit` is not an existing file and therefore will redirect to 404, add a specific section for your api before your `location / {..` section and call `/api/sessionInit` from your angular app:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass  http://nodejs/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host ;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr ;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for ;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_connect_timeout 30;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    send_timeout 30;
}
```

In `server_name`, don't put an ip but an hostname like: `mywebsite.local` then edit your `hosts` file (`/etc/hosts` on linux/max) and append `127.0.0.1 mywebsite.local`

--

*Not Question Related*

Don't bother yourself with `res.send(JSON.stringify(..))` and use `res.json(..)` which would more look like the following:

```
app.get('/sessionInit', function(req, res){
    if(sess){
        res.json({
            code : 610,
            scope : "session",
            message : "Session on the way !",
            session : sess
        });
    }else {
        res.json({
            code : 613,
            scope : "session",
            message : "Session does not exists or has expired please log in again.",
            session : null
        });
    }
});
```

Be also carful with [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and think about using [expressjs/cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) if necessary.